# itext7 exception License file was corrupted when trying to run free trial

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext7

I am evaluating itext7 Html2pdf library. I registered for a free trial, downloaded the itextkey.xml license key and included it in my project.

Here is the code I am using:

```
public static readonly string destinationFile = @"C:\Test\Generated.pdf";
public static readonly string sourceHtml = @"C:\Test\djigit.html";
public static readonly string licenseKey = @"C:\Test\itextkey.xml";

static void Main(string[] args) {
    parsePdf(sourceHtml, destinationFile);
}

private static void parsePdf(string htmlSource, string pdfDestionation) {
    LicenseKey.LoadLicenseFile(licenseKey);
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(pdfDestionation);
    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(writer);

    HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(new FileStream(htmlSource, FileMode.Open), document);

    document.Close();
}
```

When I run the project I get the following exception:

> iText.License.LicenseKeyException: License file was corrupted.

I included all the nuget packages described in the itext7 documentation in order to work: itext7, itext7.licensekey and itext7.pdfhtml.

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: For questions regarding a license key, contact the vendor directly. Stack Overflow users cannot help you.

Comment: Most common occurence of this exception: using an iText7 license with LicenseKey library v1 instead of v2. Check if you are using v2 of the LicenseKey  library

Answer (score 0):

I got up into same scenario here is the brief steps that I followed and solved

- Review and verify iText license key version from the iText_License.xml, if its 7.1 then use maven dependency version of 7.1.18 for com.itextpdf.kernel, com.itextpdf.io, com.itextpdf.layout
- Use maven dependency version of 3.1.5 for com.itextpdf.itext-licensekey, com.itextpdf.itext-licensekey-volume
- Learn more about iText maven dependency for respective iText license key version

  [iText license key installation guide](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/installation-guidelines/volume-counter-installation-guide)