# Itext7 licensekey issue for trial version

Tags: itext7

We have installed itext7 for .NET (for HTML to PDF conversion itext.pdfhtml.dll). But we could not execute the program due to licence key (licenekey.xml) issue.

Error: "Licensee element was not found"

Comment: Have you purchased a license for itext7?

Comment: Did you install the license key DLL; did you receive the trial license key; did you load the trial license key?

Comment: For questions about your iText license key, contact iText Software. See also duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44256013/itext7-exception-license-file-was-corrupted-when-trying-to-run-free-trial

Answer (score 0):

Possible things to check from your side:

- Check you're using the correct version of the license key library.
- Check your license contains the right data (it should have an element for the pdfHtml component)
- Check whether the versions match (again, you simply need to open your key with a text editor)

I would recommend you contact the sales team. Even if you are not planning on purchasing our product, we are able to offer better support (for instance we can have a look at your key).